# Skip login page is user already logged in - can't override Storyboard initial view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, authentication

I'm trying to learn IOS development and working with Swift 5 and the latest version of Xcode. I'm trying to build a simple application where the user would log in the first time only. But I'm failing to redirect the logged in users next time they open the application directly to "Home" screen which consist of `UITabBarController`. The code for checking if the user has logged in is not the issue here, I have tried everything to try to redirect the user to the `UITabBarController` from `AppDelegate` file specifically under function `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, but nothing seems to work.

I have set the login page as you see in the picture below as the "Initial View" from `Storyboard`, but can't override it using Swift. Appreciate anyone who can help with this.

[My application architecture in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6YfI.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make changes in SceneDelegate instead of AppDelegate.

```
   func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

        guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }


        self.window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
        guard let rootVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "ViewControllerIdentifierName") as? ViewController else {
            print("ViewController not found")
            return
        }
        let rootNC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootVC)
        self.window?.rootViewController = rootNC
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

Inside the function you can check if the user is logged or not.